# How Can I Concatenate Different Rows In a Single Cell Using Row_number function Without Using Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have Id, event_name, Timestamp columns.

I will concatenate last 5 event of every id.

I've used multiple WITH and JOIN to acquaire this. But BigQuery took so much time to compute.

Also this feels like such a bad practice. What can i use as an alternative?

My table looks something like this

| ID | event_name | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | a | 2022-10-21 12:10:00 UTC |
| A1 | b | 2022-10-21 12:12:00 UTC |
| A1 | c | 2022-10-21 12:15:00 UTC |
| A1 | d | 2022-10-21 12:16:00 UTC |
| A1 | e | 2022-10-21 12:28:00 UTC |
| A1 | f | 2022-10-21 12:45:00 UTC |
| B2 | c | 2022-10-21 10:12:00 UTC |
| B2 | f | 2022-10-21 11:12:00 UTC |
| B2 | b | 2022-10-21 11:25:00 UTC |
| B2 | a | 2022-10-21 11:26:00 UTC |
| B2 | f | 2022-10-21 15:32:00 UTC |
| B2 | c | 2022-10-21 15:32:48 UTC |
| B2 | f | 2022-10-21 15:36:00 UTC |

My code looks like this.

```
WITH a AS ( id, timestamp, event_name, row_number() over(partition by ID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as row_n

FROM my_table),

WITH b AS (id, timestamp, event_name, row_n

FROM a
WHERE row_n <= 5),

e1 AS(
    SELECT ID, timestamp AS ev1
    FROM b
    WHERE row_n = 1),
    e2 AS(
    SELECT ID, timestamp AS ev2
    FROM b
    WHERE row_n = 2),
    e3 AS(
    SELECT ID, timestamp AS ev3
    FROM b
    WHERE row_n = 3),
    e4 AS(
    SELECT ID,  timestamp AS ev4
    FROM b
    WHERE row_n = 4),
    e5 AS(
    SELECT ID, timestamp AS ev5
    FROM b
    WHERE row_n = 5),

concat_prep AS(
  SELECT b.ID, ev1,ev2,ev3,ev4,ev5
  FROM b
  LEFT JOIN e1 
  ON b.ID = e1.ID
  LEFT JOIN e2
  ON e1.ID = e2.ID
  LEFT JOIN e3
  ON e2.ID = e3.ID
  LEFT JOIN e4
  ON e3.ID = e4.ID
  LEFT JOIN e5
  ON e4.ID= e5.ID)


  SELECT ID, concat(ev1,',',ev2,',',ev3,',',ev4,',',ev5) as concatt
  FROM concat_prep
  GROUP BY ID ,concat(ev1,',',ev2,',',ev3,',',ev4,',',ev5)
```

And my output should look like this:

| ID | concat |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | f,e,d,c,b |
| B2 | f,c,f,a,b |

How can I optimize it? (I've already filtered by date) this query is part of a bigger query.

Answer (score 1):

Please build an array in a `group by`. There is an option to limit the elements.

```sql
With tbl as (select * , rand() as timestamp from unnest(["A1","B2"]) ID,unnest(split("a b c d e f g"," ")) event_name)

SELECT
ID,
#array_Agg(event_name order by  timestamp limit 5),
string_Agg(event_name order by  timestamp desc limit 5) as concat

from tbl
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function while `DENSE_RANK()` might rather be preferable as it arbitrarily would render including the ties(equality) of timestamp values.

So an option would be using :

```
WITH t AS
(
  SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS dr
    FROM my_table AS t
)
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(event_name ORDER BY dr LIMIT 5) AS `concat`
  FROM t
 GROUP BY ID
```

where a comma separated string would be generated by default(unless and *optional* argument **delimiter** provided after **expression** [the column *event_name* in this case] ) by using [STRING_AGG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg) concatenation function

Comment: good explanation. :o) minor correction.  "concat" column alias with double quotes is not allowed in BigQuery.  it would be better to use \`concat\` instead if needed.